# How to capture SAML Response for AWS Federated Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml, google-apps, saml-2.0

What I am trying to achieve here is to generate temporary credentials (Access/Secret Key) for the federated users logging in via GSuite SAML Application for AWS.

The AWS Console setup is fine and working properly. However, when it comes to Keys for API/CLI access, we have to manage another list which is IAM users, which kind of defeats the purpose of Single Sign On.

As per my conversation with AWS Support, we require SAML Response to generate the credentials via aws-cli:

```
aws sts assume-role-with-saml \
    --role-arn arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/saml-role \
    --principal-arn arn:aws:iam::000000000000:saml-provider/GoogleApps \
    --saml-assertion "<SAML_ASSERTION>" \
    --policy '{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Action":"*","Resource":"*"}]}' \
    --output json \
    --duration-seconds 28800
```

The above command will generate a JSON with appropriate credentials like below:

```
{
    "PackedPolicySize": 4,
    "SubjectType": "<SOMETHING>",
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "<SOMETHING>:xxx@xxx.in",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::000000000000:assumed-role/saml-role/xxx@xxx.in"
    },
    "Audience": "<SOMETHING>",
    "NameQualifier": "<SOMETHING>",
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "tbCsSecretAccessKeyGM6D/p9yPn",
        "SessionToken": "FQoDYXdzEO3//////////wEaDFUtc0bSMkDKMOZutgF",
        "Expiration": "2018-05-30T19:36:35Z",
        "AccessKeyId": "ASIAAccessKeyId5V2Q"
    },
    "Issuer": "<SOMETHING>",
    "Subject": "xxx@xxx.in"
}
```

In the above command: We get  base64 encoded code from the SSO URL ([LINK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_saml_view-saml-response.html#chrome))

[image: sso-url]

[image: saml-response]

My main issue is: How do I get the **SAMLResponse** via commandline so that I can get a script to automate to generate credentials.